# Scan through a users directory on their PC to generate xml

Tags: php, javascript, vbscript

I know asp/php are serverside etc..however...

I would like to ask a user to select a dir on their computers hard drive, and be able to generate an XML file based on files found in this directory. I would then save xml file to website .

For example directory has 3 files in it. 
c:\music\mp3\
bob1.mp3
bob2.mp3
bob3.mps

My background is vbscript/classic asp. But am happy to do this in PHP. I was wondering if JavaScript/Ajax might be my friend ??

Im not sure where to start ??

Comment: Last I checked Javascript had no ability to scan the users hard drive, neither would asp, php or some other server side language

Comment: It would be a gigantic security concern if it was possible.

Answer (score 0):

No web technology is allowed raw access to the user hard drive. You either need a browser plugin (you can write one!) or some executable on the client.